# Definition of PyBufferProcs in Python 2.7 when class implements PEP 3118

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-extensions, pep3118, pybuffer

I am in the process of extending the classes in our library
(which supports Python 2.7) to support [PEP 3118](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3118/), which has been
back-ported to 2.7.

From the documentation, I need to
initialize the `tp_as_buffer` field to point to
a `PyBufferProcs`.  From the documentation for 2.7, however, [the
description of this structure](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyBufferProcs) only contains entries for the old
buffer protocol.  From the sources, I [gather](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e307e5cd06f60e11e4e4f126fae412b9ec66a005/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#L2135-L2138) that
`PyBufferProcs` has some additional entries for the new protocol
(`bf_getbuffer` and `bf_releasebuffer`).

The questions remain:

- Do I have to do something special to tell Python that these
  new entries are valid?
- Do I have to fill in the entries for the old protocol?  (The
  documentation for 2.7 says, for example, that `bf_getsegcount`
  may not be null.  But this entry shouldn't be used if I'm
  supporting PEP 3118.)

Comment: Look at [`bytearray_as_buffer`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#l2800) in 2.7, with the additional fields for `bf_getbuffer` and `bf_releasebuffer`. Also, [`PyByteArray_Type.tp_flags`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#l2893) sets `Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_NEWBUFFER`. [`PyObject_GetBuffer`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Objects/abstract.c#l357) uses the [`PyObject_CheckBuffer`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Include/abstract.h#l534) macro to check that this flag is set.

Comment: Yes absolutely, I have looked at exactly those things – but that isn’t the problem we are asking about (unless I am missing something, those are the public, official Python API funcs – which won’t respond properly to our python C-extension objects without the proper (and needlessly cryptically documented) stuff set up in the related PyBufferProcs (as appropriately pointed at in the type struct def). Help us with getting all of that proper and correct!

Comment: The question's ["gather"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#L3648-3651) link points at Python 3's `bytearray` implementation, which doesn't use the Python 2 version of `PyBufferProcs` that has *six* fields, including the last two for the new buffer protocol. Using just the new protocol only requires those two fields. The Python 3 source also doesn't use the `Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_NEWBUFFER` flag; that's just in Python 2. Setting this flag is the "something special" that tells  `PyObject_CheckBuffer` that the new entries are valid.

Comment: @eryksun IS CORRECT. I got my objects Py_buffered this very morning with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can just fill the last two fields of `PyBufferProcs` *but* you have to add the `Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_NEWBUFFER` flag to the `tp_flags` of your types.
This is the special thing that was introduced in python2 to make the new protocol available together with the old one.

I have no idea why this isn't documented anywhere, but you can see it used in the definition of the `bytearray` type for python 2.7 (see [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#l2914)):

```
    &bytearray_as_buffer,               /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE |
    Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_NEWBUFFER,          /* tp_flags */
```

---

This content was already posted in comments, but it deserves an answer.

Comment: It cannot be overstated how correct this is – the lack of documentation for `Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_NEWBUFFER` is actually listed as a Python bug (q.v. https://bugs.python.org/issue23850) and, as @Bakuriu says, it’s the “special thing” one needs to unleash PEP 3118. Yes!